# get "group" from regex, not the match

Tags: regex

```
^(.*)\.
```

Using http://regexr.com/ I have build the above regex.

I want to get everything but the last of a "." seperated string.

i.e.

```
1.0.15.544.4 ---I need --> 1.0.15.544
```

however this regex matches

```
1.0.15.544.
```

But when I hover over the match on that website it says "group #1 : 1.0.15.544

Is there a way to get this "group" and not the match?

Comment: It depends on what tool you are using. A programming language always has a means of accessing submatches.

Comment: As Wiktor says, it depends on tool and regex flavor. But most flavors support positive look-ahead. With that you can get the whole match, without the trailing dot. I.e. `^(.*)(?=\.)` may work for you. It checks that the dot is there, but doesn't *match* it.

Comment: the context I need this for does not include any kind of application development, it just allows for regex usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with positive look-ahead. Try

```
^.*(?=\.)
```

It matches everything up to the last dot. Then it checks, without matching, that a dot follows. Note: I removed the capture group as you obviously don't need it, since it has a (very minor, but) negative impact on performance.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cX3gU9/3).